# Bug between mdframed and titlesec

Tags: titlesec, mdframed, bugs

EDIT: 
The version of `titlesec` I use is

> titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles

---

I am using `mdframed` for defining boxes and theorem-like environments.
When I load the package `titlesec`, there is a problem with the vertical alignments.

### The MWE with the bug

Here is a MWE with `titlesec` loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} % This is the cause of the wrong alignment
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[%
innerleftmargin = 0pt,
innerrightmargin = 0pt,
innertopmargin = 0pt,
innerbottommargin = 0pt,
leftmargin = 0pt,
rightmargin = 0pt,
topline = false,
bottomline = false,
leftline = false,
rightline = true
]{myBox}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFramedTheoremStyle}{%
linewidth=0pt,
innertopmargin=-1pt,
innerbottommargin=8pt,
innerleftmargin=8pt,
innerrightmargin=8pt,
skipabove=10pt,
backgroundcolor=yellow}

\mdtheorem[style=myFramedTheoremStyle]{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{myBox}
\section{test}
test
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}
\end{myBox}

\section{test}
test
\begin{theo}
Test
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The MWE how it should be

Without `titlesec` loaded, here is the result:

[image]

### My question

Is there a way to fix the bug? I use intensively `mdframed` but need `titlesec` only for the following lines

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0ex plus 10ex minus -3.5ex}{-0.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

I might drop `\section*{...}` (and also `titlesec`; I don't use `\section{}`, I only use the starred version of it) and replace it with text with the good size and format, but if someone finds how to fix the big, it is great also!

Anyway, since I have found this bug, I think it's good that it is referenced here.

Comment: `0ex plus 10ex minus -3.5ex` really?

Comment: it says if the space needs to shrink, make it larger....

Comment: What would be the natural replacement for this command?

Comment: well I couldn't guess its intended meaning:-) (looking at the subsection one possibly the same but without `-`)

Comment: I don't get the first picture with your MWE! Can you give the true code?

Comment: ??? It is the true code? Maybe we have different versions of the packages...

Comment: Yep, I have checked, with the latest version of `titles` it works.

Comment: @Colas Here, I use TeXLive 2016 with titlesec (2016/03/21 v2.10.2) and mdframed (2013/07/01 1.9b).

Comment: Ok I guess I forgot to remove the titlesec.sty new file before asking the version... I will fix that and edit the question. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of `titlesec` (2016/03/21 v2.10.2) and `mdframed` (2013/07/01 1.9b), your MWE works without problem.

Comment: Merci Paul, je travaille sur un projet lié à LaTeX et en collaboration avec l'École des Mines d'Alès, je vous envoie un mail à ce sujet ! (J'ai découvert que vous étiez aux Mines d'Albi, et le projet pourrait vous intéresser)